# Is it possible to view queries with resolved variables in ODI's code executions?

Tags: oracle-12c

In ODI's operator tab you can check the state of an execution, and inside each execution the SQL used for each transformation. On the project i'm working on we use a lot of variables when developing our ODI projects. The problem is that to debug the SQL code we have to replace the variable names with the values by hand.

Is it possible to view the executed code with the variables resolved? What would be a good workaround for this? Thanks.